# Shorthand to check sync lock flag and exit function?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to prevent one of my functions from running multiple times even if called from several different thread, but it seem's pretty clumsy.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
func doSomethingOnceAtATime() {
    var shouldExit = false
    DispatchQueue(label: "abcxyz123").sync {
        guard !inProgress else { shouldExit = true; return }
        inProgress = true
    }
    guard !shouldExit else { return }

    // Do something
}
```

I have to do it like this because `return` in the `sync` block only exits that closure, but not the function it's in. Is there a more Swifty or elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the following code offers no synchronization at all:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "abcxyz123").sync { ... }
```

That will instantiate a new queue every time you call it. Instead, you should have a property which is a single serial queue, and then use that single queue in all of your `sync` calls:

```
private let synchronizationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "abcxyz123")

func someMethodThatNeedsSynchronizedAccess() {
    synchronizationQueue.sync { ... }
}
```

---

Getting to your question about not liking the creation of the local variable before the block, I am sympathetic to that point. At the very least, I'd be inclined to pull this pattern out of `doSomethingOnceAtATime`, as well as isolate the synchronization logic:

```
class TaskState {
    private var inProgress = false
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...")

    func attemptSetInProgress() -> Bool {
        var succeed = false
        queue.sync {
            if !inProgress {
                succeed = true
                inProgress = true
            }
        }
        return succeed
    }

    func unsetInProgress() {
        queue.sync {
            inProgress = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then, your `doSomethingOnceAtATime` becomes something far more intuitive:

```
let state = TaskState()

func doSomethingOnceAtATime() {
    if !state.attemptSetInProgress() { return }

    // Do something

    state.unsetInProgress()
}
```

---

But that still has the local variable (though admittedly, encapsulated at a more logical level). If even that bothers you, we can excise that by taking advantage of the fact that the `sync` method `rethrows`. So we can do something like:

```
class TaskState {

    enum TaskStateError: Error {
        case alreadyInProgress
    }

    enum State {
        case inProgress
        case notInProgress
    }

    private var state = State.notInProgress
    private let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "sync")

    /// Try changing task status, if we can.
    ///
    /// - Note: Throw error if state already "in progress" and trying to change it to "in progress" again.

    func change(to newState: State) throws {
        try syncQueue.sync {
            if state == .inProgress && newState == .inProgress {
                throw TaskStateError.alreadyInProgress
            } else {
                state = newState
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note, the above also generalizes the "state" (in case you ever moved to more than just two states).

Then you can do:

```
let state = TaskState()

func doSomethingOnceAtATime() {
    do { try state.change(to: .inProgress) } catch { return }

    // Do something

    try? state.change(to: .notInProgress)
}
```

I must confess that while this gets rid of the local variable, I don't personally think it's any better than the prior pattern. But it's up to you.